# Excel vba to work out average score

Tags: excel, vba

[image: worksheet example]

the attached shows a small example of a scorecard i have at work for drivers, the list is many lines long, around 120 drivers, i export a report each week and it produces the attached, i have added code to tidy it up and work out scores. I then have to work out an average score for the week for each driver but can't for the life of me think how to do it using code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In a loop:  (a) Find the first row for the driver and the last row for the driver.  (b) Calculate the average of the values in column D between those rows.  (Or sum the values in column D and divide by the number of rows.)  (c) Multiply by 300.  (d) Store answer where you want it.  (On the first row?  On the last row?)

Answer (score 0):

Fill the empty cells with the respective driver names and then build a pivot table. No code required to calculate averages per driver per week. That's just a few clicks. Add more data and refresh the pivot table. No VBA. Just Excel out of the box.

You may not even have to produce the report in the screenshot, but start with the original data. Pivot tables are used for exactly that: aggregate, slice and dice large amounts of data.